Proof of the existence of the Jacobian variety of a curve over any (non algebraically closed) field
I am searching for a stand-alone and "concise" proof of the existence of the Jacobian variety of a curve over $k$ a (non necessarily algebraically closed) field.
"Stand-alone and concise" because I would like not to have to go through hundreds of thousands of page to extract the small (in percentage) amount of necessary material to make a proof.
For now I found:

Urbanik's Abstract and explicit constructions of Jacobian varieties but the most interesting proofs are omitted.
Anderson's Abeliants and their application to an elementary construction of Jacobians but $k$ is supposed algebraically closed.
Lang's Abelian Varieties in its chapter 2, but it follows the language for algebraic geometry and the treatment of Weil.
Serre's Algebraic Groups and Class Fields in its chapter 5 but he says that it follows Weil, moreover he supposes $k$ algebraically closed and refers to Samuel's Methodes d'algebre abstraite en geometrie algebrique to make it all work on any field.
Weil's Variétés abéliennes et courbes algébriques but does not use the modern language of algebraic geometry and one needs Weil's Foundations of Algebraic Geometry to understand it.
Milne's Abelian Varieties in its chapter 3 and uses the modern categorical language (representable functor).

I don't know whether Demazure and Grothendieck's SGA 3 contains what I am looking for but I fear that one needs to read thousands of pages of schemes and categories before arriving at the proof I am interested in.
So if I don't make mistake, I have 2 choices:

Weil's approach and
The schematic/categorical approach.

In any case I would have to go through a lot of material to extract what's necessary and translate it, in the case of Weil's approach, to a more modern language.
So my question is: is there somewhere (master thesis, Ph.D. or part of Ph.D.) in which the author gives a stand-alone proof without the functor approach?
$\DeclareMathOperator\Pic{Pic}\DeclareMathOperator\Div{Div}\DeclareMathOperator\PDiv{PDiv}$I think I understand that the Jacobian seen as $\Pic^0(X) = \Div^0(X) /{\PDiv^0(X)}$ is an algebraic variety as there is a bijection between $\Pic^0(X)$ and $J := X^g/S_g$ (cf. Di Piazza's Arithmetic on Jacobians of algebraic curves, page 11–13). We can bring the group law of $\Pic^0(X)$ onto $J$ but how do we prove that the group laws are "algebraic" i.e. make $J$ an abelian variety?

What background are you assuming? Hartshorne?

I changed "the Weil's approach", which seemed to be a typo, to "Weil's approach", but I admit that I did briefly picture Pedro Pascal saying "this is the Weil."  Anyway (or any Weil), what is the modern language of varieties, if not a language involving, at least in some way, schemes, categories, and/or functors?

@BenMcKay I have no precise constraint. I would like the "simplest" proof if that make any sense in the language of schemes. I mean if it can be proven without functors and categories good, without cohomology then good. But if a "more complex" result is needed then why not?

@LSpice Yes sorry "The Weil's approach" is litteral french to english. If only schemes could be involved it would be great. If one absolutely needs categories and functors then so be it.

How are you going to describe the Jacobian over $k$. It may not have any nonzero points over $k$, so that won't work. Weil's approach was to look at its points in some large "universal" algebraically closed field. The modern approach is to look at its functor of points in $k$-algebras. There really is no other way.

@anon, I don't know. I guess by considering $P := X \times_k X \times_k \ldots \times_k X$ ($g$ times), then giving a sense to $J := P/S_g$ as a scheme. $\DeclareMathOperator\Pic{Pic}$ Proving that it gives $\Pic^0(X)$ a structure of scheme over $k$ and then proving that the group law is "algebraic", i.e. there exists a morphism of schemes $f:J\times_k J\longrightarrow J$ which makes $J$ into an abelian variety and such that $f$ is "compatible" with the group law coming from $\Pic^0(X)$.
With Weil's approach I fail to see the last part, he talks about a normal law but I don't get it.

But J is not equal to $P/S_g$. I think this is closest to what you are looking for.

@anon Yes it was just to give an idea. Yes Milne seems to be the closest. The more I think to it the more I think that what I fail to see is the fact that if the functor is representable and group-valued then the underlying scheme is a group scheme. Is that right?
Well I was hoping for a proof à la Weil but with (a "simple" use of) the language of schemes.

A group structure on the functor defined by a scheme makes it a group scheme by the Yoneda lemma.

@anon That I read many times. I need to write it down properly to convince myself. Concerning Weil's approach it seems that every time I read something it's "obvious" that the group law from $\DeclareMathOperator{\Pic}{Pic}\Pic^0(X)$ is "algebraic". I went through Samuel's "La jacobienne d’une courbe algébrique". It seems to indicate that the proof is in van der Waerden's "Divisorenklassen in algebraischen Funktionenkörpern".
